# individual SQL select queries vs single big SQLselect query: what is better & why?

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization, whmcs

I have these three separate queries, here is the pseudo version of them:

```
SELECT packageid from tblhosting where userid=1234 AND id=4351
SELECT id FROM tblcustomfields WHERE relid =tblhosting.packageid AND fieldname ='foo'
SELECT value FROM  `tblcustomfieldsvalues` WHERE  `fieldid` =tblcustomfields.id AND relid=tblhosting.id
```

currently, these are separate queries & they appear as SUBqueries of each. does it make sense to combine them into single query? if yes, then why & how should one combine this?

Comment: depends on what actually you want as your final result.

Comment: I want the result of 3rd query only

Comment: The three queries seems unrelated to each other, so combine them doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: You should use `INNER JOIN` and go for a bigger query.

Comment: you should also mention that they appear as SUBqueries for the moment. Actually, this is still a non sense, just give the actual query you have...

Comment: Done, now can you please answer my question?

Comment: Optimized one query is always better !

Comment: It depends of what tables you have (size, number of columns, etc...) If you have small tables feel free to use one query, but if you have big and heavy tables - separate queryes are better solution. It is good that you don't use "SELECT *..."

Comment: if you dont want first two queries results omit them both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry to be a bit dense, but your question doesn't appear to use subqueries.

If the real code is using subqueries, along the lines of

```
SELECT value 
FROM  `tblcustomfieldsvalues` 
WHERE  `fieldid` = 
   (SELECT id 
   FROM tblcustomfields 
   WHERE relid =(
     SELECT packageid 
     from tblhosting 
     where userid=1234 
     AND id=4351)
 AND fieldname ='foo')
AND relid=tblhosting.id
```

then you only have to compare it with @Chopin's version to see that a join is far nicer from a readability point of view.

Joins are also the idiomatic way to do this - most SQL developers looking at the subquery-based approach would scratch their head; this makes it less maintainable and extensible.

In terms of performance, I'm guessing the query optimizer will recognize they're equivalent; there may not be any improvement from the "nicer" version.

Comment: It says, '#1054 - Unknown column 'tblhosting.id' in 'where clause''

Comment: For which query - my example, or Chopin's effort that should work?

Answer (score 0):

The query could be something like this:

```
SELECT value FROM tblcustomfieldsvalues
INNER JOIN tblcustomfields ON tblcustomfields.id = tblcustomfieldsvalues.fieldid
INNER JOIN tblhosting ON tblhosting.packageid = tblcustomfields.relid
WHERE tblcustomfields.fieldname = 'foo' AND tblhosting.userid = 1234 AND tblhosting.id = 4351
```

Here you're joining `tblcustomfieldsvalues` with `tblcustomfields`, and the last with `tblhosting`. Look at the `ON` conditions to be sure they're correctly joined.

Finally, apply the `WHERE` clause on the attributes you want to constraint.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This works but for some reason it returns multiple records, instead of single record returned by 3-query version

Comment: Maybe I forget something. Try adding `AND tblcustomfieldsvalues.relid = tblhosting.id` to the last `INNER JOIN` clause (as far I understood your version, you have it).